# Is there a feat to use Dex or Con instead of Str in melee (4e)?

Tags: dnd-4e

I have searched, and found some similar questions, but not this exact one.

Is there a feat (or other way, I guess) to use Dex or Con instead of Str when making melee attacks?  The only time I ever make a basic melee attack is an attack of opportunity, so I guess another way to fix this would be a way of using one of my attack powers instead of basic melee for an AoO.

As requested by commenters: I'm playing an unusual Monk build, and although I've not built for AoO-spamming, I do seem to end up with a lot of them, and as I've not got a high Str, that's left me missing most of those.

Comment: probably the most helpful thing you could do is let us see your whole build, that way we've got all of the information.

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

There is a melee training feat:

> Choose an ability other than Strength. When you make a melee basic attack using a weapon with which you have proficiency, you can use the chosen ability instead of Strength for the attack roll. In addition, you can use half of that ability's modifier instead of your Strength modifier, for the damage roll. (PHB 187(note errata), HOFL 316, HOFK 317)

This is a good strategy if you will be making a lot of melee basic attacks. However, in general it's better if you can get one of your class's attack powers to function as or be used in place of a melee basic attack.

If your monk has enough monk to have the following class features:

- Flurry of Blows
- Unarmed Combatant

Than you could partake of the "Internalize the basic kata" feat. Which allows you to use your Dex in place of your strength for unarmed strike. And it allows you to use Flurry of Blows with opportunity attacks and unarmed strike.

If you don't have Unarmed combatant than your options are basically melee training or nothing (unless you can engage in half elf cheese in which case ignore everything I've said so far and take Eldritch strike.).

Comment: Melee Training is extremely suboptimal, as Wax suggests, try to find something like the feat Power of Skill or a power that specifically lets you sub in an at-will power for your MBA.

Comment: @JoshuaAslanSmith there are a couple of classes where it can be the optimal choice, Bladesinger and Slayer would be two.

Comment: Yes, but if we're talking about dex, Slayer is already built for dex as is.

Comment: That could work... would need a little re-jiggery (he's not unarmed right now, I tried to maximize {W} damage)  If I go that route, I'll go for maximizing number of strikes instead.  Then again, 1d10+4 is better than 1d12+2, and I'll be hitting more often too, so maybe that still fits with my current build.

Comment: @Ryno is he wielding a two handed weapon? You only need a single free hand for monk unarmed strike

Comment: weapon and shield... light shield leaves the hand available for other things... does that include unarmed strike?

Comment: no. But then again, unarmed strike could totally be a headbutt...